# Am I vulnerable to an SQL injection?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am making an SSRS report, with the stored procedure listed below. My users need a search tool that will return all possible results in the name field such that a name of 'AD' should return 'ADAM' and 'MADELYN'.

I am worried that since I am using string concatenation for my where clause, is it possible that this stored procedure could fall victim to an SQL injection attack:

```
BEGIN
    @location varchar(20),@name varchar(20) 
    SELECT location, name 
    FROM   table 
    WHERE  (location LIKE @location+'%') AND (name LIKE '%'+@name+'%')
END
```

Is this code vulnerable? And, if so, how can I fix it to be safe?

Comment: I don't see a big issue there.  Your parameter is only 20 chars long limiting a lot of issue.  The way you use it in the where clause further restricts issues and no dynamic SQL with the input so I think you're good to proceed from that perspective.

Comment: You will always need to sanitize the input data on the application level

Comment: Since your location and name are parameters you are fine. Appending the '%" for like would not harm anything. This an older link on patterns and practices but it discusses store procs and stored procs with dynamic sql.  (you are not using dynamic sql so you are good) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: You are concatenating strings but you are appending a wildcard to the end of your parameter. If you were doing this with unparameterized dynamic sql this would likely be an issue but this looks fine.

Comment: @jonasfh The advice to "sanitize inputs" is misleading and often handicaps an application for no reason. I prefer "use bind variables/prepared statements" as it's less likely to lead to web sites where apostrophes are not allowed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you posted is not vulnerable to SQL injection. Concatenating string values that you use in the query is fine, it's only when you construct the query by concatenating strings together that you are vulnerable.

For code that resides in T-SQL, that means unless you're using either `EXEC` or `sp_executeSQL` you are unlikely to be vulnerable.

An example that is equivalent to your code and **vulnerable to SQL injection**:

```
BEGIN --Don't do this!
    @location varchar(20),@name varchar(20) 
    sp_executesql('
    SELECT location, name 
    FROM   table 
    WHERE  (location LIKE ' + @location + '%'') AND (name LIKE ''%' + @name + '%''')
END
```

Answer (score 2):

This part of the code, at least, is okay. Yes, you are using string concatenation, but the concatenation happens at runtime for the query, after it was compiled. The execution plan is already determined, and the result of the concatenation is only itself used as *value*; never as code. There is no way an extra `'` character or anything else could cause malicious elements of that string to leak out and be interpreted as sql code.

String concatenation is a problem for SQL strings with user data when it happens *before* compile time... either at the client code level, or on the server ahead of an `exec()` or `sp_executesql()` or similar, because the result the of the concatenation has the potential to be interpreted as code.

Of course, there may be other things in this procedure we haven't seen that still have a problem.